# Как добавить в код проверку на повтор элементов в массиве?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

Как добавить в код проверку на повтор элементов в массиве? То есть если число уже имеется в массиве - ввести другое?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    const int x = 5;
    int a[x] = {};
    cout << "VVedite chislo: " << endl;
    int i = 0;

    while (i <5) {
        cin >> a[i];
            cout << "Vvedennoe znachenie: " << "[" << a[i] << "]" << endl;
            if (a[i] < 10 || a[i]>100)
                cout << "Try one more time: " << endl;
            else
                i++;}

    cout << endl;
    cout << "This is our array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout <<"["<<a[i]<<"]" << endl;}
        return 0;}
```

Comment: Добавить проверку, есть ли число в массиве, вестимо... В чем тут у вас проблема?

Comment: пройтись по уже заполненным элементам массива, сравнивая каждый с вводимым значением. Таким образом найдете совпадение, если оно есть

Comment: Да, я это понимаю.Но вот с реализацией проблемы.Цикл нужно делать внутренним(в while)?

Comment: @ИванКравченко, да ведь нужно проверять каждый ввод. Более правильным решением будет вводить не напрямую в `a[i]`, а в дополнительную переменную, которую и будете сравнивать. Если не будет найдено совпадений - записываете в массив и увеличиваете счетчик `i`.

Comment: Вот задание:Используйте одномерный массив для решения следующей задачи. Прочитайте 
20 чисел, каждое из которых находится в диапазоне от 10 до 100 включительно. 
После того, как прочли очередное число, напечатайте его, но только в том  
случае, если оно не дублирует ранее прочитанные числа. Предусмотрите  
«наихудший случай», когда все 20 чисел различны. Используйте наименьший  
возможный массив для решения этой задачи.

Comment: std::unqiue, ему без разницы, какие элементы и какие значения.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без вложенных циклов - диапазон у вас небольшой, будем просто запоминать, какие числа уже были:

```
int main()
{
    bool was[91] = { false };
    for(int j, i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cin >> j;
        if (j < 10 || j > 100)
        {
            cout << "Wrong number!\n";
            continue;
        }
        if (!was[j-10])
        {
            cout << j << endl;
            was[j-10] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

А, только сейчас заметил про минимальный массив... Тогда так:

```
int main()
{
    int a[19] = { 0 };
    for(int n, cur = 0, i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        cin >> n;
        if (n < 10 || n > 100)
        {
            cout << "Wrong number!\n";
            continue;
        }
        bool was = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < cur; ++j)
            if (a[j] == n) { was = true; break; }
        if (was) continue;
        cout << (a[cur++] = n) << endl;
    }
}
```

Массив можно еще уменьшить - до `unsigned char a[19]` - благо, диапазон это позволяет...

Comment: Если просто запоминать какие были (в диапазоне от 10 до 100), то достаточно массива из 12 байт (91 бит).

Answer (score 0):

Можно дополнительно использовать unordered_set, т.к. это хэш он обладает быстрым поиском. Вы смотрите, есть ли элемент в set, если нет, то значит повтора не было, после этого в set надо положить этот элемент. Если элемент в set есть, то повтор.

Вот пример, дописал в Вашем коде:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

int main(){
     const int x = 5;
     int a[x] = {};
     unordered_set<int> mem;
     cout << "VVedite chislo: " << endl;
     int i = 0;
     while (i <5) {
         cin >> a[i];
         cout << "Vvedennoe znachenie: " << "[" << a[i] << "]" << endl;
         if (a[i] < 10 || a[i]>100 || mem.find(a[i])!=mem.end())
            cout << "Try one more time: " << endl;
         else 
             mem.insert(a[i++]);
     }
     cout << endl;
     cout << "This is our array:" << endl;
     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         cout << "[" << a[i] << "]" << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее простая реализация необходимого вам кода:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    const int x = 5;
    int a[x] = {};
    cout << "VVedite chislo: " << endl;
    int i = 0;

    while (i <5) {
        cin >> a[i];
        cout << "Vvedennoe znachenie: " << "[" << a[i] << "]" << endl;
        if (a[i] < 10 || a[i]>100)
            cout << "Try one more time: " << endl;
        else
        {
            ///////////////////////////_{
            int j = 0;
            bool k = 0;
            while (j < i)
            {
                if (a[j] == a[i])
                {
                    cout << "Try one more time: " << endl;
                    k = 1;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (k == 1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            ///////////////////////////_}
            i++;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "This is our array:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "[" << a[i] << "]" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```